# Adding hyperlink in a popup which comes from a polygon?

Tags: leaflet, polygon, popup, hyperlink

I need to add a hyperlink in a popup which comes from a polygon. The following piece of script shows the text which needs to be a link.

```
var polygon = L.polygon([
[51.569, -4.144],
[51.568, -4.145],
[51.57, -4.146],
[51.57, -4.145]
])

.addTo(map);

polygon.bindPopup(" RTK Survey Area ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popup content passed to `bindPopup` layer method can be any HTML formatted text, which means it can be also a hyperlink.

In your case it could be something like:

```
polygon.bindPopup('<a href="http://www.mysite.com" target="_blank">RTK Survey Area</a>');
```

Hyperlink attribute `target="_blank"` is added so that linked page is opened in new tab/window.

Comment: Great! Thanks very much!!!

Comment: If answer helped you solve your problem, it's custom here to accept it so it's clear to other visitors that problem was solved.

Comment: Yes, the answer solved my problem. Thank you!!!